# output entire table of oracle DB in website with php and save as CSV

Tags: php

I am stuck at tryping to output an Oracle table with PHP on my website.
I can only output the row information in one line at the moment, other things fail and do not give me back anything or a parse error.

What I have:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$conn = oci_connect("name", "pw", "localhost/service_name");
if (!$conn) {
  $m = oci_error();
  trigger_error(htmlentities($m['Error occured - no conenction created']), E_USER_ERROR);    

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM VIEW_DFINVENTORY 
WHERE ARTTIV NOT LIKE :didbv 
AND ROWNUM <= 100
ORDER BY ARTID';
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
$didbv = 1;
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':didbv', $didbv);
oci_execute($stid);
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC)) != false) {
echo $row['ARTID'] ."<br>\n";
echo $row['ARTCODE'] ."<br>\n";
```

This only gives me back the information like this:

```
ARTID
ARTCODE
ARTID
ARTCODE
ARTID
ARTCODE
...
```

the output with data:

```
13546987400
1234
1658198200R
1324
874312346AR
8792
...
```

How can I output the entire table/view as it is for example shown in SQLdeveloper or by outputting it to CSV with SQLPlus with all its headers and rows?

I looked around and found a loop that puts out in my case only a blank page on the browser:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$conn = oci_connect("name", "pw", "localhost/service_name");
if (!$conn) {
    $m = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($m['Error occured - no conenction created']), E_USER_ERROR);    

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM VIEW_DFINVENTORY 
WHERE ARTTIV NOT LIKE :didbv 
AND ROWNUM <= 100
ORDER BY ARTID';
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
$didbv = 1;
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':didbv', $didbv);
oci_execute($stid);
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC)) != false) {

$results = array();

foreach($results as $row)
       {
            echo "<tr>\n";
            foreach($row as $index=>$value)
            {
                echo "<td>$value</td>\n";
            }
            echo "</tr>\n";
       }

oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);
?>
```

I am new to PHP so is there something I missed? I am really stuck and trying to fix this since over 12 hours now. Some sources are too advanced for me. Maybe you know a good tutorial for this. Every approach is welcomed.

I highly appreciate your help.
Thank you already in advance,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

I'll use the second code example and add comments so you can see what actually happens :)

```
<?php
//...

/* oci_fetch_array returns you one row for the executed SQL-statement
 * in each loop run $row contains one row/line of the table.
 * $row always contains all selected columns (in your case * = all columns) of VIEW_DFINVENTORY 
 */
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC)) != false) {
  echo "<tr>";

  //you can now print out all relevant columns of one line (if you know the column name) 
  //or automatically all columns you have selected
  foreach ($row as $columnName => $columnValue){
    //print one data column
    echo "<td>".$columnValue."</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Sometimes you maybe want the first row of the table containing all the column Names (=table header) then you should add this code before the while-loop

```
$columnsCount = oci_num_fields($stid);
echo "<tr>";
for ($i = 1; $i <= $columnsCount ; $i++) {
    $colname = oci_field_name($stid, $i);
    echo "  <th>".htmlspecialchars($colname,ENT_QUOTES|ENT_SUBSTITUTE)."</th>";
}
echo "</tr>";
```